# custom drawing nsview inside nsscrollview

Tags: nsview, drawrect, nsscrollview

I'm having a problem with custom drawing NSView using as documentView of a NSScrollView.

Here is my drawRect: code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    [[NSColor lightGrayColor] set];
    NSRectFill(self.frame); // Fill entire frame

    [[NSColor grayColor] set];
    [NSBezierPath setDefaultLineWidth:1];

    float y = 0.0f;
    while (y <= self.frame.size.height) {
        [NSBezierPath strokeLineFromPoint:NSMakePoint(0.0f, y) toPoint:NSMakePoint(self.frame.size.width, y)];
        y += 50.0f;
    }

    float x = 0.0f;
    while (x <= self.frame.size.width) {
        [NSBezierPath strokeLineFromPoint:NSMakePoint(x, 0.0f) toPoint:NSMakePoint(x, self.frame.size.height)];
        x += 50.0f;
    }
}
```

[image: Drawing a grid]

Everything is OK when I scroll the view rightward, but I see strange lines when I scroll the view leftward.

[image]

I think this is a cached image buffer or something but I couldn't get why this occurs because I fill a rect which covers entire frame.

What causes this problem? How can I solve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but I just encountered the same problem and I managed to fix it.

the `drawRect` method has one argument, a `(CGRect) dirtyRect`. My mistake was that I used the dirtyRect to check for the boundaries to draw on, just like on iOS. But I discovered that this CGRect is called 'dirty' for a reason. It specifies the region that the OS wants you to redraw. This sometimes isn't the entire frame of the NSView, but a part of it. This allows you to make really fast optimized code that does't draw more than it has to.

My solution was to ignore the `dirtyRect` and instead simply use `self.bounds` for drawing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're drawing on top of the old content.
So, essentially, you need to clear it somehow.

One way is

```
[[NSColor clearColor] set];
NSRectFill(_bounds);
```

You may want something more precise or not.

Comment: Didn't work for me. I have a similar problem (image is badly damaged upon scrolling).

Comment: Make sure your rects are integral. CGRectIntegral() will help. Views hate having fractional rects